# Visual Studio: "No test matches the given testcase filter", but only when run from top level?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, test-explorer

If I run our unit tests from the top node of the project in Test Explorer, in Visual Studio 2019, none of the tests run and I get this error in the Test Output window, indicating that no tests run, failed or were skipped.  It didn't even determine how many tests there were to run:

[image: Test output log]

And then tests show up in Test Explorer like this (the red arrow indicates the node the tests were kicked off from):

[image: Run from top node in Test Explorer]

But if I kick off a test run from the next node down, the tests under that node run through to completion:

[image: Tests run (but fail)]

Any idea why running the tests from the top node in the project tree would cause the "No test matches the given testcase filter..." but running from a child node wouldn't?  We used to be able to kick off all of our tests and they would run uninterrupted.  Now we have to kick off each node individually.

Comment: I believe I saw this problem before, but updating nunit test adapter to latest version solved it.

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the adapter didn't resolve it.  I went from 2 to 3 and it's still occurring.